# How to set influx docker container listen to collectd on a specific port address?

Tags: docker, influxdb, docker-container, collectd

Few days back I started influxdb docker container using:

```
sudo docker run -d \
 --restart unless-stopped  \
 --name=influxdb \
 -p 8083:8083 \
 -p 8086:8086 \
 -v $PWD:/var/lib/influxdb \
 influxdb -config config.toml
```

then I wanted to Send Metrics from CollectD to influxdb.

and I came across this page: https://anomaly.io/collectd-metrics-to-influxdb/index.html

on which the author describes

> while 25826 is the port where InfluxDB will listen for CollectD
>   metrics

.but when I started container for influx db I did not specified any port address of 25826, so how do I make influx db aware that to listen to collectd at `25826` port address.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your influxdb instance to receive metrics from collectd, you will need to do a few things:

1. Enable the collectd listener.  You'll need to set `enabled = true` in the `[[collectd]]` section, as in:

   ```
   [[collectd]]
   enabled = true
   bind_address = ":25826"
   ```
2. You will also need to provide a `typesdb` file that informs influx how collectd metrics are structured. Possibly the tutorial to which you've linked has some details on what this file should look like. Influx will by default look in `/usr/share/collectd/types.db` for this file. It's not available in the official `influxdb` docker container, so you will need to provide your own.
3. You will need to publish the port of the collectd listener. Since this is a UDP service, you will need to add the following to your `docker-run` command line: `-p 25826:25826/udp`.

Comment: I tried this, then i tried to send sql query over http port 8086 and i get connection refused

Comment: P.S. `/usr/share/collectd/types.db` file doesn’t exist is created when metrics starts collecting?